# Where is this JSP form posting to?

Tags: jsp

I have a form in JSP that is posting to:

```
<form action="<c:url value="/servlets/apples"/>" method="post">
```

But I have no idea where it's posting to as there isn't a directory called servlets/apple.

I'm sure this is a basic JSP thing, but any guidance would be great.

Question: Where does this form actually post to?

Thanks,

NCoder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the resulting URL resolves to.

In general this will be the current host, in the current context, to whatever is mapped to `servlets/apples`.

You need to check your `web.xml` to see what the mapping is, or find where that endpoint has been annotated.

Or just look at the rendered HTML.